# Screen Distortion During Install Ubuntu Server 20.04 on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 18.04 32 bit on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, however when booting, i can not see the screen, the screen turn out to be like the font distortion as picture.

[image]

Trying to install the RaspbianOS, and it went smoothly.

Suspect there is a problem with the display driver, but how do i make some changes if i can not see the screen?

Comment: This isn't a software development question so it's not on-topic for Stack Overflow. Might be a better fit for one of [su], [raspberrypi.se] or [ubuntu.se] but you would have to check their help centres to decide which was a better fit.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved it: put your SD card into another OS, then open the file "usercfg.txt" and add this line to the end of the file:

```
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
```

Save and done! Tell me if it worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem with ubuntu mate and amdgpu in my laptop and I did the following workaround:

I started ubuntu in recovery mode. Then I opened the Desktop Settings, opened the tab 'Windows' and deactivated the option 'Marco+Compositing' in section windows manager. After that ubuntu boots as usual under these conditions. However some special effects get lost when using no compositing.